# How to send money from one PayPal acount to another through api

Tags: paypal

I'm creating a rewards app that connect with a PayPal accounts. In this app, I send money from admin site to client (which are send withdrawal request to admin). Parameters only receiver email and amount. How to integrate this with the Laravel API?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Laravel question, but the account owner can start by [applying for PayPal Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/standard/#link-getaccesstopaypalpayouts), which may or may not be granted for this business use case.